# Sunspot / Solr Full text search - how to exclude certain fields from full text search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-solr

I have implemented solr search for my rails application. I have indexed the fields for search and it is working perfectly. Now i want to exclude one particular field named Title while searching.How can i skip this particular field while searching. Is there any exclude options for the indexed text fields also.

```
searchable  do

  integer :id
  boolean :searchable
  boolean :premium
  string  :status
  time    :updated_at
  time    :created_at

  ###################################################
  # Fulltext search fields

  text :title

  text :summary 
  text :skills

end
```

Here how can i exclude only the Title field from the Fulltext search.like

```
 profiles = Profile.search do |s|
   s.fulltext @selected_filters[:query][:value] , exclude => :title
end
```

Is there any way to do like this? please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify which fields to **include** in your search

```
Profile.search do
  keywords @selected_filters[:query][:value], :fields => [:summary, :skills], :minimum_match => 1
end
```